# $ \iint_{R} \cos((3-y)^2) dx dy$ over the region $R=\{(x,y): |x-1|+x \le y \le x+1)\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

Not sure how to start this question, since $\cos((3-y)^2)$ cannot be easily integrated. I believe there is a change of variable that needs to take place but I'm not sure what values to use.

Comment: I removed the tag 3d since it's a 2d problem

Comment: start by sketching the region, then integrate w.r.t. $x$ and the integrand is indep of $x$

Comment: Did you try to express the integral as $$\int_1^3  \int_{y-1}^{\frac{y+1}{2}} \cos\big((y-3)^2\big)dxdy$$

Comment: @MatthewHolder Yes i have done, but then you would need to integrate something in the form of $\int_{1}^3 \frac{y+1}{2} \cos((y-3)^2) - (y-1)\cos((y-3)^2) dy $ Where would you go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you need to calculate $$\iint_{\mathscr{R}:\{(x,y):|x-1|-x\leq y\leq x+1\}}\cos((3-y)^{2})dxdy$$
Now, by definition we need to evaluate
$$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{g_{1}(y)}^{g_{2}(y)}\cos((3-y)^{2})dxdy$$
Since that region of integration is $$\mathscr{R}:\{(x,y):|x-1|-x\leq y\leq x+1\}$$
so, we get $$g_{1}(y)=y-1 \quad \text{and} \quad g_{2}(y)=\frac{y+1}{2}$$
and $$a=1 \quad b=3$$
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\iint_{\mathscr{R}:\{(x,y):|x-1|-x\leq y\leq x+1\}}\cos((3-y)^{2})dxdy&=&\int_{1}^{3}\int_{y-1}^{\frac{y+1}{2}}\cos((3-y)^{2})dxdy\\
&=&\int_{1}^{3}\cos((3-y)^{2})\left[\frac{y+1}{2}-(y-1) \right]dy\\
&=&\int_{1}^{3}\cos((3-y)^{2})\frac{y+1}{2}dy-\int_{1}^{3}\cos((3-y)^{2})(y-1)dy\\
&=&\left(\sqrt{2\pi}C\left[2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \right]-\frac{\sin(4)}{4}\right)-\left(\sqrt{2\pi}C\left[2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \right]-\frac{\sin(4)}{2}\right)\\
&=&\boxed{\frac{\sin(4)}{2}-\frac{\sin(4)}{4}}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $C(x)$ is the[Fresnel $C$ integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Definition).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!